# Applescript string will not change when using set var2 to "oos"

Tags: applescript

```
set var to "select bleh"
set question to display dialog var buttons {"bleg", "blerg", "bleegh"}
set answer to button returned of question
set var to "yes or noe"
set var2 to "e"
set question to display dialog var buttons {"yeg", "noeg"}
if answer = "yeg" then
    set var2 to "oos"
if var2 = "oos" then
    say var2
    tell application "Notes" to activate
end if
```

I tried changing the variable "var2" to equal "oos" but it will not change. If it does not change, it will not the 2nd if statement

Comment: The syntax of this code is invalid -- it has two `if` statements, but only one `end if`. Did I misformat it? In any case, please correct it. Also, I'm not understanding what's wrong. Please explain 1) what buttons to select to see the problem, 2) what you expect to happen, and 3) what actually happens that's different from what you expect.

Comment: I have fixed what you told me to but it does nothing. Problem: It will not set var2 to "oos" and because of that, the script 'if var2 = "oos" then
    say var2
    tell application "Notes" to activate
end if' will not work. When the script runs, you select one of 3 buttons. In this case I clicked "bleg" because it is the one with code. You then click "yeg" and I expected that clicking yeg would set var2 to oos. I expected to open notes after wards.

Comment: The variable `answer` is set to the selected button from the *first* dialog box, not the second, so it'll always be either "bleg", "blerg", or "bleegh", and never "yeg".

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you're missing another

```
set answer to button returned of question
```

following the second dialog box. Without it, the `answer` variable is still carrying the reply of the first box.
Also, to get it to compile, you need an `end if`. Hard to guess your logic, but I think you mean two separate ifs, in which case it goes before the second `if` statement.
A cleaner way to do this is:

```
set var to "yes or noe"
set var2 to "e"
display dialog var buttons {"yeg", "noeg"}
set answer to button returned of the result
if answer = "yeg" then
    set var2 to "oos"
else if var2 = "oos" then
    say var2
    tell application "Notes" to activate
end if
```

Notes:
What's the point of the first dialog box... you don't ever do anything with it?
You don't need to set the dialog box to a variable if you're not going to reference the variable.

Comment: Thank you! About your question, it was a test script I did as I just learned a tiny bit of apple script. I was going to add more stuff for the other buttons.

Comment: Nevermind, it gives me this error: The variable question is not defined.

Comment: yes, oops.  I eliminated using the "question" variable, so that line needed to change to "button returned of the result". I changed it.

Comment: It changes var2 to oos, but the else if does nothing.

Comment: It does everything your does-nothing original script does. Your original question was why the Var2 was never changed to "oos". I answered that and fixed it, pointing out your missing capture of the second dialog button choice.